# VxWorks O.S. libraries

Tags: vxworks

My question is the following:

do I need to recompile all the VxWorks O.S. libraries for the target architecture each time I switch between my projects, one for Pentium M and one for Atom?

If this is the case, is there some smart strategy to shorten the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

In the case you have sources of vxworks in your distribution you can create source build projects for each BSP and build them. These projects produces the complete set of libraries. You can create VIP (vxworks image project) based on source build project and your image will be linked with the libraries you produced. One thing to remember - the source build project doesn't contain sources, but only links on them, so if you will change the source in one source build project it will be changed in all projects and the next build will change the produces library. So be aware of it. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use SCCS (source code control system, like git, cvs, clearcase, whatever), then create two local workspaces from the same repo (one for Pentium M, and the other for Atom). When you make changes in one workspace you commit the change to the repo, and then merge those changes into the other workspace.